# How to use header redirect in PHP AJAX Call In Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating a login form and I need to redirect the user to his/her profile page! I am using AJAX Requests so header redirect is not working at all. It just stays on the homepage. 
 So how can I redirect the user to another page in pure javascript PHP ajax call? Please give the answer in pure javascript. I don't like to use jQuery at all!

Javascript:

```
function ajaxCall(){
    var xhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    var parameters = 'email='+document.getElementById('email')+'&password='+document.getElementById('password');
    xhttp.open('POST', 'login.php', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www/form/urlencoded');
    xhttp.send(parameters);
}
```

Login.php(PHP)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $ema = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($ema) && !empty($pass)){
        if($ema === 'Bill' && $pass === 'Cool'){
            header('Location: https://www.google.com');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have written so far?

Comment: header('Location: profile.php') not working at all in AJAX! Is there a another way to redirect the user in pure javascript!

Comment: Aaah! OK! @Bluefire

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @Bill in what sense is it not working? Is there an error message?

Comment: @Bluefire No not all! It just stays on the home page!

Comment: @Abaddon666 This is not possible duplicate question to the question you mentioned. The question you mentioned just talks how to redirect to other webpage only in Javascript.

Comment: @Bill You wanna to redirect when ajax right?

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya Yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an ajax call.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['location'=>'/user/profile/']);
exit;
?>
```

The ajax response will return something like

```
{'location':'/user/profile/'}
```

In your ajax success javascript function

```
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299)
            {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if(response.location){
                  window.location.href = response.location;
                }
            } 

    }
```

Comment: Isn't that success jQuery? If not how should i use in Javascript AJAX?

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! I just couldn't figure out your solution. But really thanks a lot! Marked as answer :)

Comment: What's the purpose of adding && xhr.status < 300 ?  It will return false if it's not 200.

Answer (score 1):

I landed here looking for an Ajax solution, nevertheless MontrealDevOne's answer provided useful. If anyone else is curious about the ajax method too, here you go:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form_register', function (e) {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'form_submissions.php',
          data: form.serialize() + "&submit",
          dataType:"json",
              success: function (data) {
              if(data.location){
                window.location.href = data.location;
              }
          },
          error: function(data) {
              alert("Error!");
          }
      });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Just my 2 cents, hope it helps :)

Comment: this totally helped better understand the top answer - appreciate it bud

Answer (score 0):

try this bill if its works.

```
  window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: No i am not talking about javascript redirect. I need PHP Header Redirect which is not working in AJAX Call!

Comment: @Bill try this once in your ajax code when you need to redirect if its works to redirect header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro! But got the good one from @MontrealDevOne

Comment: @Bill Roger Captan :)